# React not updating component when performing deep updates of props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a Component that has a prop which is an array which I'm using to to map over and return a child component for each item in that array. Each of those items is another array of objects. However, when I perform updates to an item in an inner array like this:

```
    let newInnerArray = getInnerArray(itemIndex); //assume this is a function that gets the correct inner array by the index

    newInnerArray[innerArrayIndex].name = "changed name";

    arrayObjs[itemIndex].innerArray = newInnerArray;
```

The react component doesn't update because I've performed an update to an inner array and didn't change the number of them (which would trigger an update).
Here's a simplified version of what the prop looks like to clarify:

```
    [{
        name: "name 1",
        innerArray: [
            {
                innerName: "inner name 1"
            }
        ]
    }]
```

So in my Component, the prop that I'm mapping over is the outer array there. And when I update one of the prop's item's "innerName", no update is fired for that component.

To trigger an update, I'm adding a dummy attribute to each of the outer array's items and updating it every time I make an updated to the inner array like this:

```
arrayObjs[itemIndex].date = performance.now(); //using performance.now() because it always produces a unique value
```

Making the prop now look like this:

```
[{
    name: "name 1",
    date: performance.now(),
    innerArray: [
        {
            "innerName": "inner name 1"
        }
    ]
}]
```

This works but is very hacky. Is there a better way to force a component to update every time I update an inner array in one of its props?

PS: sorry if I didn't explain this well or it's confusing. I'll explain further if someone doesn't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Seems because `React` is doing shallow-compare in your case. When comparing objects, shallow-compare only compares their references ("do they point to the same object ?"). There are several options here I can think of:

- Use [immutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) for your state. I am doing this way in my application.
- Create a clone (copy) of your inner array

```html
    const innerArray = getInnerArray(itemIndex);
    let newInner = [...innerArray];
```

- Manually compare your new `props` using `shouldComponentUpdate` with `lodash` [isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isEqual) (or  [underscore isEqual](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual)).

Comment: Two things: the innerArray is already being cloned, and I tried using the third method and it's still not working. I'd rather solve this with shouldComponentUpdate for not because it's the least instrusive solution